# Error creating Zoom conference with Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I'm using the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar) to programmatically create calendar events for users. I want to give users the option to include a Zoom meeting while creating their event (assuming they have the Zoom add-on for Gcal).

However, I get the following error when I try to create the event:

`"Invalid conference type value."`

Here is the body of my request (using the REST API):

```
data = {
    summary: ...,
    start: {...},
    end: {...},
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        requestId: uuid4().toString(),
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: "addOn"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I used the type "addOn" per the allowed key types defined in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events).

Another weird observation is that, when I pull my calendar metadata using the CalendarList API, under `allowedConferenceSolutionTypes`, only `"hangoutsMeet"` is listed. However, I double-checked in the Google Calendar client and I definitely have the Zoom add-on enabled.

Is this a bug in the Google Calendar API? Anyone have any pointers on how to create 3rd party conferencing meetings while creating GCal events?

Comment: Is your app an [Addon](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types#g_suite_add-ons)? In this case, did you implement the conference solution also in the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons)?

Comment: No, it's a Chrome Extension. The particular addon we want to include is Zoom.

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not possible as confirmed by those two issues:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167461857
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158019329

Even though the documentation of [conferenceData](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#conferenceData.conferenceSolution) seems to suggest that it is possible:

> The conference solution, such as Hangouts or Google Meet. Unset for a conference with a failed create request. **Either conferenceSolution and at least one entryPoint, or createRequest is required**.

However the API returns an error if someone tries to do exactly that:

> Cannot have multiple conferences of type Hangout and NamedHangout

I created a feature request, so I would suggest to go there and "vote" for it:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167533577