# Cannot create a Zoom conference via Google Calendar API using "addOn" conferenceSolutionKey type

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

At my company we use auto-generated Zoom Meetings via the "Zoom Meeting" third-party add-on for Google Calendar.

For the [API spec to insert a new Google Calendar event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert), you can pass a `conferenceSolutionKey` to determine what kind of conference should be created (e.g. `hangoutsMeet` for Google Meet).

On the [global spec](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource) I'm seeing that there exists the type `addOn` for the `conferenceSolutionKey`, but when attempting to use it with

```
'conferenceData': {
    'createRequest': {
        'requestId': <random id>,
            'conferenceSolutionKey': {
                'type': 'addOn',
            },
        },
    }.\,
},
```

I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` with `[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Invalid conference type value.'}]`.

Should I be sending this request differently somehow? Or is the spec mistaken and `type: addOn` is only allowed in non-`createRequest` context?

NOTE: I see the extremely similar [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979973/error-creating-zoom-conference-with-google-calendar-api?rq=2), but it looks like the feature has been further implemented over the past three years -- at the very least, it's now possible to insert existing data via the API on creation i.e. if I were to create the Zoom Meeting myself and send up the data outside of a `createRequest`, but whether it can be created with the Calendar event remains questionable.